# Get problem with Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, msbuildcommunitytasks

I copy the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.xsd file in MSBuild Commnunity Tasks source code to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild\ folder of Visual Studio to get the Intellisense for the tasks but it doesn't work!

I did try to add the schema using the property pane when editing the .proj files but whenever I add the .xsd file, the Intellisense will stop working immediately. I tryied to turn it off (by removing it from the schemas in the property pane), my script with MSBuild Community Tasks 's tasks run files but no Intellisense then.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of [Intellisense for MSBuild Community Tasks doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2516145/437934).